# How to solve chromium and certificate error while doing npm i

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm, puppeteer, chromium

I have cloned the project from github and trying to run the react project in VS code.
I ran npm i and also tried npm i --force.
This is the log

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\55393\Desktop\Rapidx_Documentation\website\node_modules\puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
    
npm ERR! ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r722234! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
    
npm ERR! Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
    
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

How to solve this?

I have attached package.json below

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "examples": "docusaurus-examples",
    "start": "docusaurus start",
    "build": "docusaurus build",
    "serve": "docusaurus serve",
    "publish-gh-pages": "docusaurus-publish",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus-write-translations",
    "version": "docusaurus-version",
    "rename-version": "docusaurus-rename-version",
    "swizzle": "docusaurus swizzle",
    "deploy": "docusaurus deploy",
    "docusaurus": "docusaurus"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v17.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.28.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.4.4",
    "@docusaurus/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects": "^2.1.0",
    "@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@docusaurus/preset-classic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.3",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.8.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "docker": "^1.0.0",
    "docusaurus": "^1.14.7",
    "docusaurus-lunr-search": "^2.1.15",
    "docusaurus-pdf": "^1.2.0",
    "docusaurus2-dotenv": "^1.4.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-markdown-editor-lite": "^1.3.2",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.3",
    "react-player": "^2.10.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: (1) _"I have cloned the project from github and trying to run the react project in VS code. "_ <-- could you clarify this? what is the project you cloned from Github? (2) how is React related? (3) could you share at least the relevant part of your `package.json` (e.g. puppeteer version)? (4) what is your Node version?

Comment: It is a react js project. It is a website. Node version is 16.13.2.

Comment: I have added package.json file above

Comment: upgrade to at least node 17.6 (as set in the package.json) and try again